# count child from parent child php mysql 5 level deep

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, parent-child

Folks,
I am badly in need of counting every member on each level I have 5 level deep Commission model so I am able to count the first level but not able to count whole team a person have in his / her down line. I want to count how many members on each level like
 **on 1st level 2 members, second level 34 members, third level 7 members etc.** 
I am sharing my sql table here

`id   fname        rid  cnt`

`1  NetCash          0  3`

`2  Mian Salman     1   5`

`3  Zeeshan Murtaza 1   2`

`4  Usman Liaqat    1   2`

`5  Javed Iqbal     2   1`

`6  Faysal Islam    2   0`

`7  Waqas Pervaiz   3   0`

`8  Bashir Ahmad    5   0`

`9  Mirza Amir      2   0`

`10     Tauqeer Saghir  2   4`

`11     Asif Butt       4   0`

`12     Abdul Qayum     10  0`

`13     jhangir abbas   10  1`

`14     Ansar Mahmood   13  0`

`15     M USMAN KAYANI  10  0`

`16     Jabir Hussain   2   0`

`17     Abdul Rehman    10  0`

`18     Adnan javed     3   1`

`19     muhammad irfan  18  0`

`20      khurram        4   0`

I need to count the whole number of members for Parent id / rid = 1 
on 1st level , 2nd level ... up to 5th level.
I am able to count on first level like
 `SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts FROM`user_table`WHERE rid = 2`  
if you need any clarification please comment i will explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something, you simply could use a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS counts, rid AS level FROM user_table WHERE rid<6 AND rid>0 GROUP BY rid
```

Comment: I think you have not read what i need I want to count every member on each level.
like on first level rid  have 5 members and now i want to get all member on second level hope you will understand.

Comment: @SKDevelopers Yes, that's what this will do

Comment: Dear do you have any solution for my problem i need it badly?

Comment: There is no answer for my question a long time ago 
i am still waiting answer.

Comment: I am still looking for this answer please any one can explain recursive count call to my problem.

Comment: I did read it again, I guess I don't understand? "on 1st level 2 members, second level 34 members", where do these numbers come from? There are not even 34 users... What is a level? Is rid the parent's id? What is cnt?

Comment: Dear it is for demo and i want to count members on each level rid is parent ID